# I cannot succeed in editing a bibliography

Tags: bibliographies

I have two problems:
(1)I want to change my use package that includes 
`file contents`
(2) I want to understand what type of style I shall use with natbib, because mine it's not compatible.
I am using Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019).

These are the codes, that I put in:

```
\begin{filecontents}{aporia99.bib}
    @book{moore2004principia,
        author = "Moore, G.E.",
        title = " Principia Ethica",
        year = "2004",
        publisher = "Dover Publications",
    }

\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}  
\usepackage{bibentry}         
\nobibliography* 

\begin{document}

\author{Antonio Freiles}
\title{Can emotions give us access to values?}
\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
\noindent 

this would be \cite{moore2004principia}




\end{abstract}

\section{Introduction} 
\noindent 
Before proceeding with my inquiry 


\bibliography{aporia99}

\bibliographystyle{apalike}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please update your question with an actual question. What is your problem? It is not clear from your question title either. BTW: remember that `filecontents` only writes the file once! If already existing it will never be overwritten. If you have a very modern latex installation you can pass an option to the `filecontents` env such that it will always overwrite and existing file.

Comment: I cannot cite properly, it shows a question tag. The console says that "my file.bib" already exists on the system. So what package should I use? @daleif

Comment: The second problem is that Natbib is not compatible with author year citation how can I change that?

Comment: natbib *is* compatible with author-year, `apalike` is not compatible with `natbib`

Comment: And again please update your question and write exactly what your problem is

Comment: I have done it can you answer my question about filecontents

Comment: Please also specify in your question which latex installation you are using and whether it is up to date (for example this line from the top of the log file is very relevant, on my system I have `LaTeX2e <2019-10-01> patch level 3` and I'm using TeXLive 2019). What is that `bibentry` stuff suppose to do here?

Comment: BTW: your example compiles witthout problem for me. Note I did not have `aporia99.bib` in advance, you can try and delete `aporia99.bib` from disk then run pdflatex, bibtex, and the pdflatex twice. If you have a new enough latex you can use `  \begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{aporia99.bib}` and it will overwrtite the `.bib` file on each compilation.

Comment: It says I have to use the extended mode to use the overwriting, but I do not know how I have to do it. Do u know how to do it?

Comment: Extended mode? Where do you see extended mode? Do you mind updating your question with the contents of the log file for the compilation on your end of this particular example

Comment: If I add overwrite, my console says that' an error

Comment: Then you are not up to date, and you'll probably need to move that file contents intop the preamble and use the `filecontents` package.

Comment: There is another way to do the citation and bibliography Can I Change the code? "file contents"

Comment: Just remove the filecontents and edit the .bib file separately, you can use your latex editor

Comment: Can you explain better? If I remove the file contents,the bibliography does not work.

Comment: The `filecontents` env creates a file on disk (the option of the env). Since you have an old setup, this will be written only once and never updated unless you delete the generated `.bib` and rerun latex. Having the `.bib` in the tex file like this is only handy for minimal examples like this, not for real projects. Instead let latex create the `.bib` file. Then  remove our outcomment the `filecontents` from your document (in your example, everything down to `\documentclass`). Then if you need to update the `.bib` file, open the file in your editor, there is presumable an File -> Open and edit

Comment: You're basically shooting yourself in the foot if you want to keep editing the `.bib` file as a part of your `.tex` file. You'll need to know what you are doing especially since you have an old latex setup.

Comment: Thank you, can you give me an example through some codes written down?

Comment: I have posted an answer that shows how to produce an author-year citation. Please either accept the answer (if it works for you) or edit your question to explain what you need beyond the result in the example I have provided. As it stands, there is a risk your question may be closed.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this is really an answer, but it's an attempt to rescue the question rather than closing it...

Create two files. First, whatever.tex:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}

\begin{document}

\author{Antonio Freiles}
\title{Can emotions give us access to values?}
\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
\noindent
this would be \cite{moore2004principia}
\end{abstract}

\section{Introduction}
\noindent
Before proceeding with my inquiry

\bibliography{aporia99}
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\end{document}
```

Then, aporia99.bib:

```
@book{moore2004principia,
        author = "Moore, G.E.",
        title = " Principia Ethica",
        year = "2004",
        publisher = "Dover Publications",
}
```

Then do:

```
pdflatex whatever
bibtex whatever
pdflatex whatever
pdflatex whatever
```

This works for me, and produces an author-year citation: "this would be Moore (2004)".